# AKs has worse ev than random hand?

Tags: ev

I'm playing around with the pokereval library, and saw that e.g. on preflop, if I have AKs, then my ev decreases.

```
E.g. 3 players
random pocket  35%
random pocket  35%
AKs  29.8%
```

How come? I thought it is a strong hand and my ev would increase. Can anyone explain this to me.

Comment: Pocket means "pair". In your hand. That's why it's not coming out as you'd expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't comparing AKs to any random hand, you're comparing it to a random pocket pair. As per http://www.tightpoker.com/poker_hands.html, the EV of AA-JJ is significantly higher than AKs and as such skews the group "random pocket" enough to be better than AKs.

AKs is still the 5th best starting hand in poker statistically.

Comment: I'm not convinced that it is pairs. Docs says unknown card

Comment: Well something isn't right, because http://poker.cavalie.ro/starting_hand_odds#strength_against_random_hand is generated using poker_eval and puts AKs vs 2 villains at 50.7%

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie Really you think random pocket means any hand?  Why would they use the term pocket for any?

Comment: I'm pretty sure AKs is the 4th best starting hand...

Comment: Because of the cavalie link I could figure out that I send my arguments incorrectly. My board list was empty instead of empty pockets (using pypoker-eval). I now also get the correct ev, `'ev': 507`. That is what I expected. Thanks!